# TableView/CoreData Subtitles and Title

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, tableview

I am making a list app and have a Coredata model with two attributes in it (One for item and one for details)

I can save and input data and it will be displayed correctly but when i close and reopen the app, everything has its own cell.

Any help guys?

**Code For CellAtIndex**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")! as UITableViewCell
    let item = listItems[indexPath.row]
    let detailed = detailedItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.valueForKey("item") as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = detailed.valueForKey("detail") as? String
    return cell
}
```

**Code For ViewWillAppear**

```
verride func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    //Load First Item
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let fetchrequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ListEnt")
    do{
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchrequest)
        listItems = results as! [NSManagedObject]
        detailedItems = results as! [NSManagedObject]
    }catch{
        print("Error")
    }
}
```

Here is the code for saving, I have a dialog box appear, with to text field, and each text field has its own save function

```
 //Saving Items//
func saveItem(itmToSave: String){
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("ListEnt", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    item.setValue(itmToSave, forKey: "item")
    do{
        try managedContext.save()
        listItems.append(item)
    }catch{
        print("Saving Main Item")
    }

}
//Saving Details
func saveItem2(itmToSave2: String){
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("ListEnt", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let item2 = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    item2.setValue(itmToSave2, forKey: "detail")
    do{
        try managedContext.save()
        detailedItems.append(item2)
    }catch{
        print("Saving deatil Item")
    }

}
```

**Pictures of the problem**

How it looks when you input data (Correct way)

[image: How it looks when you input data (Correct way)]

How it looks when you close and reopen the app

[image: How it looks when you close and reopen the app]

Cheers Guys

Comment: How are you creating and saving your "ListEnt" objects?

Comment: First I don't understand what is your problem.Can you describe it in bigger detail? And second why don't you try NSFetchedResultsController - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/

Comment: Can you show here your more code because not proper details here related your problem.

Comment: Problem is when you reload the app the item and item details appear in different cells not in the same subtitled cell.

Comment: You deleted your previous question, but my comment is still relevant: "Why do you have two arrays? Doesn't `ListEnt` has the two properties?

Comment: Yah Sorry, thought i would delete it and start again, explain it better this time, I think i have solved it, with your help, why did i have two arrays?, i have created a class, with item and details in and go from there, think i have solved it, We will see, thanks for your help!!!